How to recognize if a sequence can represent the number of handshakes among $n$ people?
Inspired by the following problem, I have a more general question:

$6$ peoples attend to a party, which of the following sequences can represent the number of handshakes of each person at the end of the party?
$a)5,4,3,2,2,0\qquad b)5,4,3,2,2,1\qquad c) 5,4,3,2,1,1\qquad d) 2,2,2,1,1,1\qquad e)5,4,3,3,2,1$

This problem is not hard to solve, I noticed the total number of handshakes should be an even number, so we are only left with the options $(c)$ and $(e)$. From here it is not hard to deduce the option $(e)$ is possible for examples by writing the number of handshakes explicitly.

I'm interested about the sequence of number of handshakes of $n$ people where similar to the above example not necessarily everyone shakes hand to each other. For example, if we are given a sequence of $100$ numbers how we can recognize if it is possible to be the number of handshakes among $100$ people or not?
Mathematically speaking to generate the sequence of the handshakes of $n$ people which we represent by $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ we can start by $0,0,\ldots,0$ ($n$ zeros) and we choose the elements $k,m$ where $k\neq m$ and add $1$ to $x_m$ and $x_k$. And to check if the sequence represents the number of handshakes or not we do this process backward and we replace $x_m$ and $x_k$ with $x_m-1$ and $x_k-1$ until we are left with all zeros.
I want to know more about such sequences and wonder if they are already well-explored. I'm especially interested to see if there are methods for recognizing if a given sequence can be the number of handshakes or not.

"Degree sequence"

@tehtmi Thanks a lot, you can post it as an answer if you want.

I'll also add that this is a form of the Graph realization problem and can be solved by the Havel–Hakimi algorithm
